# Graphing $x^{3 / 2} + y^{3/2} =1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions

My brother asked me what I thought was a fairly straightforward question, graph the function below over the real numbers:

> $$ x^{3/2} + y^{3/2} = 1.$$

[image: Original graph]

Now of course, we can't have any negative values in the square roots, so the graph looks 'similar' to the graph of a standard circle in the +X+Y quadrant of the XY plane. This is all well and good, next however; we simply rearranged the formula to:

> $$ y = \left(\left( 1-x^{3/2}\right)^{1/3}\right)^2$$

And this is where the confusion began. Now, it's clear that substituting a large x value would simply produce a large negative value inside the bracket, squaring this would simply make the value positive. So now the graph of the function contains all of the points that made up the original graph, plus another branch of values:

[image: Manipulated graph]

This is unexpected. What step in my algebra permitted these positive values?

Comment: Over-round circle.

Comment: @eccstartup: Under-round, actually. It’s between the circle and the line $x+y=1$.

Comment: Well, thats why I said it was similar :) I know its not a circle.

Comment: Under-round, you're right. I mistook $3/2$ by $5/2$. This is just a curve.

Comment: Not to be confused with the [Astroid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroid)

Comment: $\sqrt a=b$ necessitates both $a\ge0$ (domain of the square root) and $b\ge0$ (range of the square root). From some answers, I see that confusion between these two conditions remains. You concern relates to the second one, which induces $x,y\le1$ (the first inducing $x,y\ge0$).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It happened when you squared both sides of

$$y^{1/2}=\left(1-x^{3/2}\right)^{1/3}\;.$$

Consider a similar but simpler example: $y^{1/2}=x$; clearly $y=x^2$, but because squaring wipes out the sign, it’s also true that $y=(-x)^2$, even though in the original equation $y^{1/2}=x$ we must have $y\ge 0$.

Comment: $y\ge 0$ is mandated by the square root, but you also need $x\ge 0$ to fulfill $y^{1/2}=x$.

Comment: @Yves: Of course, but (a) the OP was already aware of that, and (b) it doesn’t affect the answer to the OP’s specific question: the problematic step was the squaring.

Comment: Mentioning $y\ge0$ when what matters is $x\ge0$ keeps the confusion going.

Comment: @Yves: I do not think that you’ve diagnosed the problem correctly. The confusion was simply failure to recognize that squaring in this case introduces an extraneous solution, and I addressed the reason for that.

Comment: @Yves: On the contrary, the crucial point is that we must have $y\ge 0$ in order to talk about $y^{1/2}$. And of course that doesn’t rule out the possibility that $y=(-x)^2$; I did not say that it did.

Comment: No, all plots agree with $y\ge0$. The discussion is about $x>1$ allowed or not.

Comment: @Yves: As far as I'm concerned the only question at issue is what step of the OP's calculation caused the problem. We're in agreement on that. You apparently want to deal with the specific way that it caused trouble here; I prefer to deal with what I see as a more fundamental point.

Comment: @brianmscott: you visibly deny that the answer has nothing to do with $y\ge0$. I am stopping this sterile discussion.

Answer (score 4):

$\sqrt y=f(x)$ is not equivalent to $y=f^2(x)$, simply.

(You introduce an extra solution $\sqrt y=-f(x)$. You must enforce $f(x)\ge 0$, which amounts to $x\le1$ here.)

---

Said differently, the domain of the square root is the positive reals, so that the curve is restricted to $x,y\ge0$.

And the range of the main branch of the square root is limited to the positive reals as well, so that (after simple computation) the curve is restricted to $x,y\le1$.

When rearranging the equation, you allowed solutions that invalidate the range condition (square root that yields a negative value).

Comment: Why this downvote ?

Comment: this is the correct answer , rest all nonsense.

Comment: ERROR: incomplete reply comment, unable to understand.

Comment: Downvoting this means not having understood the point. You have my sympathy, because you're right and the downvoters are wrong.

Comment: @egreg: thumbs up !

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the ambiguity: is $y^{1/2}$ positive or negative? where $y^{1/2}$ might be defined to be a solution of $z^2=y$.

If you rearrange the other way, you get a third curve, that is the mirror image of your second curve.
$$x=\left(\left(1-y^{3/2}\right)^{1/3}\right)^2$$

Comment: There is no ambiguity: for real numbers $y^{1/2}$ **is** defined as the non-negative solution of $z^2=y$, if there is one.

Answer (score 1):

The exponent is 3/2 , a cube of square root, so must carry both signs  $ \pm $ associated with square root even if not explicitly stated.There is a combination of three curves depending on (+,+),(+,-)(-,+)choices as shown.

$$ \pm\; x^{3/2} \pm y^{3/2} = 1 $$

( None of them are second degree of course even if so by appearances).

$$  x^{3/2} + y^{3/2} = 1 .. (1*) $$

is a slim "circle" and

$$  x^{3/2} - y^{3/2} = 1 ..(2*) $$

is a slim "rectangular hyperbola" that has cusp touching x-axis.

$$  -x^{3/2} + y^{3/2} = 1 ..(3*) $$

is a slim "rectangular hyperbola" that has cusp touching y-axis.

EDIT1:

Every square root has an $ \pm $ implied always in its relational existence. Recognition or choice *cannot deny its implied existence*.

Although some curves with symmetry are best plotted *parametrically*, only first quadrant is covered in this particular case due the even number 4 in numerator of exponent:

ParametricPlot[ {Cos[u]^(4/3), Sin[u]^(4/3)}, {u, 0 , 2 Pi}],

but the "hyperbolae" need proper domain choice.

ParametricPlot[ {Sec[u]^(4/3), Tan[u]^(4/3)}, {u, -Pi/3, Pi/3}].

EDIT2:

[image: SexticNarrowAngle]

I added egreg's sextics with my $ \pm $ *two curves*

$$ ( x^3 \mp  y^3 )^2 - 2 ( x^3 \pm y^3)^2 + 1 = 0  ... (4*) $$

in Red and Blue ..showing how everyone's right!

Comment: You made the confusion with exponent $2/3$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: Thanks, corrected graphing error.

Comment: Do you really mean that $\pm$ is implied? Then what's the value of $\sqrt{4}+\sqrt{1}$? Choose among $3$, $1$, $-1$ and $-3$. This is nonsense, if you express it this way.

Comment: @egreg I hope it would start making sense once you associate (+,+) with the "circle", (+,-) for the branch cusped on x-axis, and (-,+), for the branch cusped on y-axis.I shall label them if that makes it more clear.

Comment: I don't agree; it is true that the given locus is *part* of the sextic $(x^3-y^3)^2-2(x^3+y^3)+1=0$, which can help in understanding it. But as it was written, only $x\ge0$ and $y\ge0$ can be used.

Comment: @egreg: Changed the graphs to explain further. I am replying to OP's query about what brings in the hyperbola cusped graphs. The sign change is for coefficients of the equation, but not for the domain signs.

Comment: @egreg: Every square root has its sign  $ \pm $ implied always in its relational existence. Recognition or choice cannot deny its implied existence.

Comment: @Narasimham I beg to differ. Doing so confuses the concept of function with the concept of “solutions of equations”. They are *different* things. For any positive real number $r$ there are two real numbers whose square is $r$. But $\sqrt{r}$ is positive ***by definition***.

Comment: @Narasimham The sextic has no $\pm$, if you have a point the squaring is to eliminate those. And the convention I'm used to is that $x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ allows for branches but if you write $\sqrt{x}$ you have chosen the positive one.

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland: Right.But there is no way you can bring both the curves as demanded by OP into the same cooking pot.Can you or anyone suggest a unification without recognizing the reality of either sign?

Comment: @Narasimham: Thank you for this, you really went above and beyond to explain this! I found it very helpful!

Comment: Welcome, no problem. Being associated with $ \sqrt{.} , $ the reality of $ \pm $ operations should not be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Should be a comment. If you allow both signs for the square root: $x^{\frac{3}{2}}+y^{\frac{3}{2}}=1$ can be squared twice $x^3=(1-y^{\frac{3}{2}})^2=1-2y^{\frac{3}{2}}+y^3$ so $2y^{\frac{3}{2}}=1+y^3-x^3$ making $4y^3=(1+y^3-x^3)^2$ and this has the plot:

[image: plot]

What we see is that $(\sqrt{x})^3+(\sqrt{y})^3=1$ is part of the sextic, where $(-\sqrt{x})^3+(\sqrt{y})^3=1$ and $(\sqrt{x})^3+(-\sqrt{y})^3=1$ are the other branches.

Comment: The equation reads $(\sqrt x)^3+(\sqrt y)^3=1$, and you are limited to $0\le x,y\le1$, as the arguments of the roots must be non-negative and the roots themselves are non-negative.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Why do you choose the positive roots?

Comment: To make the expression $x^{3/2}+y^{3/2}$ a function, one must choose a branch. The OP didn't write $\pm x^{3/2}\pm y^{3/2}=1$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I come from algebraic geometry, where multibranch is no problem. He didn't write $(\sqrt{x})^3+(\sqrt{y})^3=1$ either.

Comment: In any case, the question is "What step in my algebra permitted these positive values", which you don't address.

Comment: Ok, it should be a comment.